# Abrir Layout al dar click a imagen que se encuentra en un ListView

Tags: android-studio

tengo una duda al mostrar un Layout, cree un Adapter (AdapterProducto.java) donde inicializo elementos de Layout(layout_list_producto.xml), finalmente mando llamar el Adapter en mi ArticuloActivity.java el cual está asociado con un Layout (activity_articulo.xml) donde tengo un ListView y muestro mis datos, lo importante es que tengo una imagen en el Layout  layout_list_producto.xml donde solamente inicialice el elemento, pero lo que estoy intentando hacer es que al darle clic a la ImageView abra un Layout (modal_add_product.xml).

Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Gracias

> AdapterProducto.java

```
public class AdapterProducto extends ArrayAdapter<Producto> {
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<Producto> lProducto;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;


    public AdapterProducto (Activity activity, int textViewResourceId,ArrayList<Producto> lProducto) {
        super(activity, textViewResourceId, lProducto);
        try {
            this.activity = activity;
            this.lProducto = lProducto;

            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return lProducto.size();
    }

    public Producto getItem(Producto position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView txtVID;
        public TextView txtCodigo;
        public TextView txtDescrip;
        public TextView txtVPrecio;
        public ImageView imgAgregar;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        final AdapterProducto.ViewHolder holder;
        try {
            if (convertView == null) {
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_list_producto, null);

                holder = new AdapterProducto.ViewHolder();
                holder.txtVID = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtVID);
                holder.txtCodigo = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtCodigo);
                holder.txtDescrip = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtDescrip);
                holder.txtVPrecio = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtVPrecio);
                holder.imgAgregar = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imgAgregar);

                vi.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (AdapterProducto.ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
            }

            holder.txtVID.setText(Integer.toString(lProducto.get(position).getId_articulo()));
            holder.txtCodigo.setText(lProducto.get(position).getCodigo());
            holder.txtDescrip.setText(lProducto.get(position).getDescripcion());
            holder.txtVPrecio.setText(Float.toString(lProducto.get(position).getPrecio_mayoreo()));


        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return vi;
    }
}
```

> layout_list_producto.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/card">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="No Venta"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtVID"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtCodigo"
                    android:text="KD546SD"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="60dp"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="10dp">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtDescrip"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="Producto"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"

                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="50dp">
                <TextView
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:text="$"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small.Inverse"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                <TextView
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:id="@+id/txtVPrecio"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp"
                    android:text="150.15"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small.Inverse"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgAgregar"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_plus_circle_solid"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


    </LinearLayout>
```

> ArticuloActivity.java

```
public class ArticuloActivity extends Activity {

    public ListView listProducto;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_articulo);

        // Inicializo los elementoS
        listProducto = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listProducto);

        List<Producto> productos = new ArrayList<Producto>();
        IProductoDAO dao = new ProductoDaoImpl();
        productos = dao.obtener();

        final AdapterProducto adbProducto;
        adbProducto= new AdapterProducto (this, 0, (ArrayList<Producto>) productos);
        listProducto.setAdapter(adbProducto);

    }
}
```

> acitivity_articulo.xml

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bg_screen1">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listProducto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

> modal_add_producto.xml (Este es el Laout que quiero mostra al dar
>   click a imagen)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#199ec2"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_exit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="Hola"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: prueba agregando a tu imagenView `android:focusable="false"`

Comment: Hola, lo que quiero hacer es que al dar click a la imagen que se encuentra en mi ListView abrir un Layout, pero de lo que he investigado y se es que es con un OnClic o un ItemOnClic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es crear una `interfaz` en tu `Adapter`.

```
public interface AdapterProductoListener {
        void onClickImageViewSelected(int position);
    }
```

Después modificar el Constructor para pasar como parámetro la interfaz

```
...
private AdapterProductoListener listener;
...

public AdapterProducto (Activity activity, int textViewResourceId,ArrayList<Producto> lProducto,AdapterProductoListener listener) {
        super(activity, textViewResourceId, lProducto);
        try {
            this.activity = activity;
            this.lProducto = lProducto;
        this.listener = listener;

            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
```

Agregarle el evento click al `ImageView` :

```
    holder.imgAgregar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.onClickImageViewSelected(position);
        }
    });
```

En tu actividad modificar la instancia de tu Adapter, creando una instancia de la interfaz `AdapterProductoListener`

```
    adbProducto= new AdapterProducto(this, 0, (ArrayList<Producto>) productos, new AdapterProducto.AdapterProductoListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClickImageViewSelected(int position) {
            //Producto producto = productos.get(position);
//Abrir el Modal
        }
    });
```

Comment: Ya hice eso, pero ahora no se están poniendo mis datos en el ListView, como si no trajera datos, porque el ListView esta vacio.

Comment: Traia comentado el codigo,perdon.Listo ya quedo, muchas gracias :3 ♥

Answer (score 1):

En tu clase adaptador debes sobreescribir el metodo del evento click:

```
holder.imgAgregar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //aqui tu intent 
    }
 });
```

Comment: Ya había hecho eso y para comprobar imprimir un dato y si funciono porque me trajo el dato correcto, pero quiero que se abra modal_add_producto.xml en vez que me imprima un dato.

Comment: O como le hago para que al presionar la imagen me encime como si fuera una modal arriba del Activity que tengo, no importa si se tiene que crear un Activity

Comment: puedes crear una DialogFragment

Comment: ya lo cree ahora como es como lo debo de llamar y pasarle un parametro para que se muestre en la vista del DialogFragment